# What do i need to change in my code to avoid sheets by sheetname.startswith in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, startswith

My current code is able to do as desired and make changes in all sheets based on filename that starts with a certain string. But, i just realized that some of the sheets within the file may have slightly different names in the months going forward.
My code-

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
cols_to_drop =  ['PSI ID','PSIvet Region','PSIvet region num']              
column_name_update_map = {'Account name': 'Company Name','Billing address':'Address','Billing city':'City'} 

for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/hhh/Desktop/gu/python/PartMatching"):
    if file.startswith("PSI"):
        dfs = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)
        output = dict()
        for ws, df in dfs.items():
            if ws in ["Added"]:
                continue
            if ws in ["New Members 03.22", "PVCC"]:   #sheets to avoid
                temp = df
                temp['Status'] = "Active" if ws == "All Members" else "Cancelled"
            #drop unneeded columns
            temp = df.drop(cols_to_drop, errors="ignore", axis=1)
            #rename columns
            temp = temp.rename(columns=column_name_update_map)
            #drop empty columns
            temp = temp.dropna(how="all", axis=1)
            temp['Partner'] = "PSI"
            output[ws] = temp
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{file.replace(".xlsx","")} (updated headers).xlsx')
        for ws, df in output.items():
            df.to_excel(writer, index=None, sheet_name=ws)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
```

My goal is to make my current code avoid the sheet whose name starts with "New Members". But as you can see in my code I have to specifically mention New Members 03.22. This sheet next month will be named New Members 04.22 and so wont be compatible with my code to run on a scheduled task. I tried if ws.startswith in ["New Members 03.22", "PVCC"]: but nothing happened.

Comment: Do you absolutely need the number in the string? And what is PVCC for?

Comment: If it changes the name according to the date, a probable solution such as a variable that checks the current date or the one you want and stores it in 'date' and opens the worksheet with the new name, would it solve your question?

Comment: @MarkRansom pvcc is another sheet i want my code to avoid. I dont need the number in string. I just need my code to recognize that any sheet with begins with the word 'New Member' and 'PVCC' should be avoided and not picked up when applying the functions in my loop below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startswith` can only be used with one string at a time, so you need to break up the test.

```
if any(ws.startswith(x) for x in ["New Members", "PVCC"]):
```

Comment: Thanks for your respnse Mark. Unfortunately, the sheets are still present after i run the code with this change.

Comment: Hey, i think i figured out why i did not work. I placed your code before 'continue' and it worked. Thank you. Marking this as correct as it was just a matter of placement